# Unwanted rewrite data in List

Tags: c#, list, collections, reference, generics

I have problem with store data in list collection. If I add new data it rewrite old data, and in list is still only one item.

Here is main method, from this method I call method OpenChatScreen, It’s method of ChatScreenManager class where is root of problen.

```
    private void OpenTabChatWindow(string nick)
    {
        try
        {
            new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
            {
                IDetailData oponent = new DetailData();

                oponent = Service.DetailData(Account, nick);

                Execute.OnUIThread((System.Action)(() =>
                {
                    //here I call problem method OpenChatScreen method where is the problem,
                    //it use still the same reference on object opponent
                    if (ChatScreenManager.OpenChatScreen(true, Account, oponent, Account.DetailData.Info.Nick))
                    {
                        AddConversationHistory(nick);
                    }

                }));
            }

            ).Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MsgBox.ShowException(exception);
        }
    }
```

Code from ChatScreenManager class:

```
             public IDictionary<string,object> ActiveChatScreens { get; set; }

or 
             public IList<string,> ActiveChatScreens { get; set; }
```

Problem is same if I use dictionary or list.

```
       public bool OpenChatScreen(bool useTabChat, IAccount account, IDetailData oponent, string avatarNick)
            {
                if (!ActiveChatScreens.Contains(oponent.Info.Nick))
                {
                    if(useTabChat)
                    {
    //in this method - OpenTabChat is problem
                        OpenTabChat(account, oponent, avatarNick);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            private void OpenTabChat(IAccount account, IDetailData oponent, string avatarNick)
            {
                if (!ChatShellViewModel.IsActive)
                {
                    OpenChatShell();
                }

                ChatShellViewModel.OpenChatTab(account, oponent, avatarNick);

//here is the root of problem, it use same reference of object opponent
                ActiveChatScreens.Add(oponent.Info.Nick);
            }
```

So I pass from method OpenTabChatWindow object type of DetailData and store som string property in List in another class, but is use same reference on this object and rewrite data in list.

I try create new insatce of object:

```
                IDetailData oponent = new DetailData();

                oponent = Service.DetailData(Account, nick);
```

And pass this object to problem method, but it didn’t solve it.

Comment: What datatype is ActiveChatScreens?

Comment: Sory, my mistake, I edited my question. It is list, or it can be also dictionary. Problem is same I store opponent.Info.Nick to collection. But it use same reference on object opponent and rewrite item in list.

Comment: If you use the same reference in a dictionary it should overwrite previous content. If you are trying to add new messages you need to use a messageid as key and in the object it contains have properties for who and what. Is this the case or are you trying to open new chat windows and then why is it a problem that it overwrites?

Comment: NO. I use collection dictionary or list on checking if screen with some id is active or not. I add  new instace of object, see OpenTabChat method => IDetailData oponent = new DetailData();, object opponet has string property Nick, Nick is key in dictionary. So I add key pair value Tom, object and then Mike, object and this rewrote Tom,object in dictionary. For this action is in dictionary only  pair Mike, object. I know my english horrible, do you understand me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now if I understand your examples.

You add objects to ActiveChatScreens.

Could it be that you are reusing the same object in the call to OpenChatScreen in the first place.

Id so then opponent will change and any reference to it will also change before these methods is even called?

Remember objects are reference structures, even if you change the data in them, the reference is still the same.

Comment: Yes, you have right ChatShellViewModel class is singleton-> it case this problem. Thank you.